# Showing that $f$ and $g$ are analytic continuations of themselves.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a^n z^n$$
$$g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{(1-a)^n z^n}{(1-z)^{n+1}}$$

From this, I have:

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{1-az}, |z|<\frac{1}{|a|}$$
$$g(z)=\frac{1}{1-az}, |z||a-1|<|1-z|$$

I want to show that the two regions have some sort of overlap where an open set could be stuck, so that would prove they are analytic continuations, but I don't know how to do that. Would appreciate any hints. From what I've looked at Wolfram for some particular values of $a$, the region looks pretty complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint:* The intersection of two open sets is open and $0$ belongs to both regions.